# numpy array float number division leads to strange behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, floating-accuracy

Please follow the code lines:

```
A = np.array([0 for i in range(10)])

A[:] = 0.1/2

A

Out[36]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

A[:] = float(0.2/2)

A[:]

Out[38]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I can't understand, why numpy is giving such a strange behavior?

I am using numpy 1.13.3

Comment: Check your dtype of A after init.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you define your array it is of `dtype=int`. Define it as `float` and it will work as you expect.

example:

```
a = np.arange(10) # dtype = int
a[:] = 0.1 # converts to int so to 0
print a

a = np.arange(10.) # dtype = float
# or equivalently a = np.arange(10, dtype=float)
a[:] = 0.1 # works as you expect
print a
```